# JSDoc, type variables

Tags: jsdoc, type-variables

Can we have type variables in **JSDoc**?
For example I want to define identity function:

```
/**
 * @param {a} x
 * @return {a}
 */
const id = x => x;
```

But when I use it with concrete types `id(2)`, editor always complains that type `number` is not  assignable to type `a`. I understand why, as in **Haskell** or other similar languages the lower cased names in annotation is treat as type variable, but JS views it as concert type.
So is there a way to define type variables in **JSDoc**?

PS: Yea, I know that there is TS and Flow, and I should use them in stead of playing with annotations, but the project I'm working on now is not ready to be migrated to TS, but in same time I want to make things as safe as possible using JS only.

Comment: Do you mean `@typedef`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're asking for a type definition for a method where the `@param` type is always the same as the `@return` type?

Borrowing from [the Closure Compiler's Wiki: Declaring a bounded generic type](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Generic-Types#declaring-a-bounded-generic-type):

```
 /**
  * @param {A} x
  * @template A
  * @return {A}
  */
 const id = (x) => x;

 /** @type {string} */
 let str='';

 /** @type {number} */
 let num=1;

 str=id(true); // Type warning.

 str=id('string'); // Type safe.

 str=id(1234); // Type warning.

 num=id(true); // Type warning.

 num=id('string'); // Type warning.

 num=id(1234); // Type safe.
```

Produces the following warnings:

```
JSC_TYPE_MISMATCH: assignment
found   : boolean
required: string at line 16 character 0
str=id(true)
^
JSC_TYPE_MISMATCH: assignment
found   : number
required: string at line 20 character 0
str=id(1234)
^
JSC_TYPE_MISMATCH: assignment
found   : boolean
required: number at line 22 character 0
num=id(true)
^
JSC_TYPE_MISMATCH: assignment
found   : string
required: number at line 24 character 0
num=id('string')
```